# Is "shop " a CVC word or a CCVC word?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Is *shop* a CVC word?

Or, to rephrase the question, in the CVC structure, do **C** and **V** each refer to a single sound or to a single letter?

As I see it, a C or a V means a sound, and a sound could be 1 or 2 letters, so I thought a word like *sh-o-p* or *b-a-th* is a CVC word.

Just now someone told me that in CVC, C or V refer to a letter, so *shop* is a CCVC word.

Is that right or wrong?

Answer (score 7):

**C** and **V** here only ever refer to sounds, never to letters. The word *shop* is pronounced either [ʃɒp] or [ʃɑp] depending on your accent, so it’s a CVC word: one consonant sound, one vowel sound, and one consonant sound. **Letters never matter**.

Answer (score 2):

English orthography and phonology are very different. And syllable structure has nothing to do with orthography, it's about sounds. So it's CVC word.